# VSTS: Send deployment failures to distribution list?

Tags: azure-devops

When a deployment fails, only the person who triggered the deployment receives notification. I'd like the failure email to go to a distribution list so that it's not missed in case the person who triggered it is not available. Is this possible in Azure DevOps and if so, how do you do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a custom notification for the specific group:

- Go to `https://[account].visualstudio.com/_admin/_notifications?tab=Subscribers&view=Subscribers`
- Choose your group:
  [image]
- Click on "New Subscription"
- Choose like the following image:
  [image]
- Configure the alert (with your project name etc.):
  [image]

Comment: I had to select a specific group to get to the second screen, but this looks like it fulfills the need. Thanks.